# Nginx location 301 returns with dynamic arguments

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

What is best practise to use a 301 return in a location block in nginx with a url that has dynamic arguments like the below:

```
    location = /property/:propertyId/requests {
            return 301 /property/:propertyId/requests/open;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below

```
location ~ ^/property/(?<propertyId>\d+)/requests/?$ {
    rewrite ^ /property/$propertyId/requests/open permanent;
}
```

I have assumed the property id is a number and used `\d+`, but if it is alphanumeric you can change the pattern